# Логика работы последовательности трансформаций в transform

Tags: svg, inkscape

До конца не понимаю как работают трансформации в SVG.

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height: 400px;" viewBox="-100 -100 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line x1="-200" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="-200" x2="0" y2="400" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="aqua" ></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="green" transform="scale(2, 2)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Почему `scale` сделали не вокруг центра фигуры, а от начала координат, ведь теперь фигура не просто увеличилась но и сдвинулась... Тогда вопрос как её увеличить вокруг центра?

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height: 400px;" viewBox="-100 -100 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line x1="-200" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="-200" x2="0" y2="400" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>  
    
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="green" transform="translate(-20,-20) scale(2, 2)"></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="aqua" ></rect>
</svg>
```

В данном случае я фигуру первым действием `translate(-20,-20)` возвращаю в начало координат, как я думаю, и при масштабирование фигура должна остаться у координат `0,0`, но она всё-равно сдвинута остаётся, почему?

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height: 400px;" viewBox="-100 -100 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line x1="-200" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="-200" x2="0" y2="400" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="green" transform="translate(-20,-20) scale(2, 2)"></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="red" transform="scale(2, 2) translate(-20,-20)"></rect>
</svg>
```

В чём разница этих двух вариантов? Правильно ли я понимаю что преобразования выполняются с конца?

Как правильно повернуть фигуру на 45 градусов и увеличить в два раза относительно её центра?

```
<rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40" fill="blue"></rect>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я немного изменил  исходный код автора, чтобы не учитывать смещение относительно начала координат, которое задает `viewBox="-100 -100 400 400"`, чтобы в чистом виде посмотреть, как влияет команда `scale(2)` на позиционирование фигур.

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height: 400px;" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="blue" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="400" stroke="blue" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="aqua" ></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="green" transform="scale(2, 2)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Если левый верхний угол прямоугольника не совпадает с началом координат, в вашем случае  `<rect x="20" y="20"` сдвинут по горизонтали и вертикали на `20px`. то при применении команды `scale(2)` все параметры прямоугольника умножаются на `X2`  и координаты левого верхнего угла становятся - `40,40px` ширина, будет равна width="80",высота height="80" на рисунке это зеленый квадрат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы вернуть увеличенный, зелёный квадрат в исходную позицию 20x20px нужно применить команду `translate(-20 -20)`.
Если команд трансформации несколько, то они выполняются  от последней к первой 
`transform="translate(-20 -20) scale(2 2) "`

```html
<svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0" stroke="blue" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="400" stroke="blue" stroke-dasharray="5 5"></line>
  
   <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="green" transform="translate(-20 -20) scale(2 2) "></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="aqua" ></rect>
    
</svg>
```

**Пример масштабирования вокруг точки**

Допустим у нас есть точка с координатами `50,50px` вокруг которой мы будем масштабировать прямоугольник, таким образом, чтобы он увеличивался, без смешения от этого центра.
Механизм центрирования тот же. Считается насколько увеличилось расстояние от начала координат до центра фигуры и вычитается размер, чтобы вернуть фигуру на прежнюю позицию.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<!-- центр масштабирования -->
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="2" style="fill: black;" />
<!-- первоначальный прямоугольник -->
<g id="box" style="stroke: black; fill: none;">
<rect x="35" y="40" width="30" height="20" />
</g>

<use xlink:href="#box" transform="translate(-50,-50) scale(2)" style="stroke-width: 0.5;" />
<use xlink:href="#box" transform="translate(-75,-75) scale(2.5)" style="stroke-width: 0.4;" />
<use xlink:href="#box" transform="translate(-100,-100) scale(3)" style="stroke-width: 0.33;" />
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял что в последнем примере `translate(-100,-100)` параметры `translate` рассчитываются математически?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Так везде рассчитываются математически Можно даже формулу вывести От центра было 50, умножили на 3 стало 150, чтобы вернуть обратно вычитаем 100

Comment: хорошо бы что бы была функция `scaleFromCenter`, что бы не пришлось это вычислять вручную. Для функции поворота можно центр указывать.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин тебе все карты в руки, алгоритм понятен, надо его в JS зашить

Comment: Получается если я захочу анимировать плавное увеличение прямоугольника относительно центра, просто мне надо координаты прямоугольника указать сразу относительно его центра, то есть вокруг `0,0` и потом помещаеть его через `translate` и тогда `scale` анимация не будет смещать объект.

Comment: Возможно тогда хорошая практика все фигуры сразу в центрированных координатах делать... может не везде, но в некоторых ситуациях полезно будет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин пробуй, тут главное принципы понять